# How to populate ArrayList in text file to JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jcombobox

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList` to a `JComboBox` when it is clicked.

Here are the pictures, and I also want to how to get and information after ":" so i make calculation eg 1 USA:1.02 
 -> get the value after :1.02 when ID 1 is selected then calculate the value from the users input from the text field 1 to populate the result.

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/i54v0n.png]

**This is the code :**

```
private void cbCountryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    try{
        //File reader method
        FileReader file = new FileReader("/Users/MacbookDev/Desktop/countryrates.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            text += line;
            line = reader.readLine();

        }
        cbCountry.addItem(text);

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? post an MCVE
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oh, I fortgot to say, the above code doesn't reflect on combobox at all

Answer (score 2):

```
    while (line != null)
    {
        text += line;
        line = reader.readLine();

    }
    cbCountry.addItem(text);
```

Don't create a string of all the text in the file. You need to add each line of text to the combo box as a separate item:

```
    while (line != null)
    {
        cbCountry.addItem(line);

        line = reader.readLine();

    }
```

Also, if you want to store multiple pieces of data in the combo box, then you need to create a custom Object for the data and then create a custom renderer to display the data. See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thank you, I will have look at the Combo Box With Custom Renderer examples